# Logrotate Error : unknown option & unexpected text

Tags: centos, logrotate

I am trying to use logrotate ,

I have create file in logrotate.d directory with "rotatetest" name. Please see below detail in file:

```
/etc/rsa/rotatetest {
 create
 size 100k
 rotate 10
 missingok
 compress
 dateext
 postrotate
        service rsyslog restart
endscript
}
```

when i tried to run *logrotate -f rotatetest* , it given error as below

```
error: rotatetest:1 unknown option 'Oct' -- ignoring line
error: rotatetest:1 unexpected text
error: rotatetest:2 unknown option 'Oct' -- ignoring line
error: rotatetest:2 unexpected text
error: rotatetest:3 unknown option 'Oct' -- ignoring line
error: rotatetest:3 unexpected text
```

Answer (score 1):

When you give the command `logrotate -f rotatetest` to rotate the logs according to the `rotatetest` configuration file, the command would pick up the `rotatetest` file from the *current directory*.

It seems plausible that your current working directory may be `/etc/rsa`.  This would cause `logrotate` to try using your *logfile* as its configuration file.  Since it can't make heads or tails of the logfile, it complains.  It's the `Oct` string in the error message that makes me think that it tries to use the logfile as a configuration file.

Instead, use

```
logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/rotatetest
```

so that `logrotate` picks up the correct configuration file.